# WP Contact Form 7: Submit Form to two different URLs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

i am trying to build a Form with the WP Contact Form 7 Plug-In, which submits its result to two different Forms on other pages (depending on which of the two submit buttons is clicked)
Here the content of the CF7-Form in the Backend:

```
<label class="input"> [date* arrival] </label>
<label class="input"> [date* departure] </label>
<label class="input"> [number* occupants] </label>
<p>[submit "Request: Target URL 1"]</p>
<p>[submit "Booking: Target URL 2"]</p>
```

The Target URL 1 contains another CF7-Form to which the values are beeing submit to. The Target URL 2 contains a third party Form which the values also are beeing submit to. (values are beeing passed correctly)

I am using the Plugin 'Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension' to pass the values to the next CF7-Form and also 'Contact Form 7 Redirection' in addition to CF7.

The problem is, that i cannot define Multiple Target URLs depending on which submit button is clicked.

Is there a possibility to solve this issue using the 'Additional Settings' Field in CF7?

Thank You

**EDIT:**

I now got the redirection working using a DOM event, but the values are not beeing passed to the target page with this code:

```
document.getElementById("submitID").onclick = function(){myFunc()};
  function myFunc() {
  location.href = "http://targeturl/";
}'
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

The additional settings do not have a specific option to address this that I could see, but you can use DOM events and create a function for the submit buttons. (The Javascript code option was removed at the end of 2017, so you have to use DOM events instead.)  You could use the `onclick` event and create your options from there. Here is some information from the Contact Form 7 website on how they handle DOM events:  https://contactform7.com/dom-events/

Comment: Thank You! I now got the redirection working, but the values are not beeing passed. (Details in post)